# Outputting HTML with "variable" Wrapper Class

Tags: php, html, css, arrays, loops

I need help on looping through an array, and displaying formatted HTML display and of course CSS styling. But the main problem is: I can't figure out how to adjust the correct way of wrapping it and choosing the name of the wrapper class. Because I need to loop the array to find the correct class name.

In other words: I need to calculate the amount of time between "Today" and the expire date, if it is too close to expiring, I want to change the wrapper class to "nearExpire", else don't change it. But since the calculation is AFTER the wrapper echo, I can't call a variable yet not declared. So I tried to append the loop values and then wrap it, but it didn't work because the loop kept duplicating values.

Sorry if I'm not being clear, English is not my native language. Here is a generic code for what I mean (tell me if I'm unclear, I'll try to explain better later):

### Generic Array for Code

```
// A generic array adquired from a database
$myArray = [
    [0] => [
        ['id'] => 15
        ['anotherTableID'] => 4447
        ['description'] => 'GenericDescription'
        ['created'] => 2000-01-01 12:00:00
        ['expire'] => 2005-01-31 12:00:00
    ],
    [1] => [
        ['id'] => 35
        ['anotherTableID'] => 327
        ['description'] => 'AnotherGenericDescription'
        ['created'] => 2000-01-01 12:00:00
        ['expire'] => 2000-01-31 12:00:00
    ],
];
```

### Code

```
echo "<div class='mainWrapper'>";
foreach ( $myArray as $cardArray ) {
    echo "<div class='cardWrapper", $myHTMLClass", '>"; //  <-- Here I need to echo the class
    foreach ($cardArray as $cardKey => $cardData) {
        switch ( $cardKey ) {
            case 'expire':
                if ( calculationOfExpire() == "3 Days Left" ) {
                    $myHTMLClass = " nearExpire";
                }
                echo $cardData;
            break;
            default:
                echo $cardData;
            break;
        }
    }
    echo "</div>";
}
echo "</div>";
```

And the point of this is to display all "CardArrays" side by side, but each with it's own unique "maybe Expire" class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do something like this:

```
...
foreach ( $myArray as $index => $cardArray ) {
    $myHTMLClass = '';
    if (calculationOfExpire($cardArray[$index]['expire']) == "3 Days Left") {
        $myHTMLClass = 'nearExpire';
    }
    echo "<div class='cardWrapper" .  $myHTMLClass . "'>"; //  <-- Here I need to echo the class
...
```

Or for a 1-liner:

```
...
foreach ( $myArray as $index => $cardArray ) {
    echo "<div class='cardWrapper" . ((calculationOfExpire($cardArray[$index]['expire']) == "3 Days Left") ? ' nearExpire' :'' ) ."'>"; //  <-- Here I need to echo the class
....
```

This is just using the index of the current card to get the `expire` index, which you can do your calculation on.